# How do I skip specific/individual scenarios in same story using meta filtering?

Tags: java, junit, spring-tool-suite, jbehave, thucydides

When doing bdd/testing with JBehave/Thucydides I would like to skip certain scenarios that I know are working temporarily. Eventually, I want to re run the whole test suite. However, as I am developing, re-running old tests just to get to new tests I have written takes too much time.

Here is an example of what I am talking about:

**loggingIn.story**:

```
Scenario: logging in as customer
...

Scenario: logging in as admin
...
```

I know first scenario works, how can I skip it instead of regoing through it when I run the story using JUnit?

From the JBehave website links
[Meta Info](http://http:http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-info.html),
[Meta Filtering](http://http:http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html)

I gathered I could do something as follows:

**loggingIn.story**:

```
Scenario: logging in as customer
Meta:
@ignored true
...

Scenario: logging in as admin
Meta:
@ignored false
...
```

Then when running the test as a JUnit test case, I passed a jvm argument as follows: 
`-Dmetafilter="+ignored"`.

However, this skips both scenarios instead of just the first.

Comment: You want to skip them forever?  Or until a certain point in time?  How would JUnit know when to start testing them again?

Comment: I edited my post to clarify. I want to skip them temporarily. JUnit would know to start testing them again when I remove the meta filters I suppose. I don't know too much about the meta filters is why I am asking.

Answer (score 2):

I opened a same question some days before because I had a similar question. However your argument `Dmetafilter="+ignored"` means that all scenarios with the meta tag `@ignored` will be executed. You don't have to use `true` or `false` after `@ignored`. If you want to skip all scenarios with the meta tag `@ignored` you have to use `Dmetafilter="-ignored"`.

I am using something similiar like `-Dmetafilter="+run -norun"`. This means that all sceanrios with the tag `@run` will be executed and all scenarios with `@norun` will be skipped (I know, you usually need only one of them but that makes it more clearer for me in the scenarios which should run and which not).

**EDIT:**

So a example would be:

```
Szenario: Validation of something
Meta:
@norun
Given ...
```

Comment: Hmm I did something now that makes your answer not totally true. I have all my tests annotated with @skip and I am passing the jvm as -Dmetafilter="+skip" so I expected all them to be executed but it skipped all of them.

Comment: That is strange. Do you have any space characters or something like that? I'm regularly using these meta parameters in my maven run configuration as a goal (e.g. `clean verify serenity:aggregate -Dmetafilter="+category:one"` , in this case all scenarios with tag `@category:one` will be executed others will be skipped and it works fine for me). You can also read it here: http://jbehave.org/reference/stable/meta-filtering.html `where [+|-] indicates if the filter should include or exclude the meta property and [...]`

Answer (score 2):

Most of the Jbehave examples I have looked at make use of the Skip metadata to do what you are proposing.

```
Scenario: logging in as admin
Meta:
@skip
Given ...
```

Your filter then looks like `-Dmetafilter="-skip"`.  You do not need to have on/off values.  If it has a skip meta value of then it will be skipped.